# Stop a running loop by clicking a button in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I want to create a code that loops over an array and prints its index. I have created buttons to ***Stop*** (to stop the loop) & ***Start*** (to start the loop) the loop.

I have tried to achieve this by creating a condition that checks over a variable `stop`, If its value is `1` the look should stop, however, this condition doesn't work.

Comment: are you using vanilla js or any of the frameworks like Angulat, React, Vue, etc?

Comment: Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example we cannot help without seeing relevant code, for example how are you pausing between printing out each number?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use recursive method and settimeout to set loop time (if needed)

```js
let isStatus = false;
let index = 0;

function myLoop(){
  console.log(index++)
  setTimeout(function() {   
    if(isStatus) {
      myLoop()
    }
  }, 800)
}

function start(){
  index = 0
  isStatus = true;
  myLoop()
}


function pause(){
  isStatus = false;
}


function resume(){
  isStatus = true;
  myLoop()
}
```

```html
<button onClick="start()">start</button>
<button onClick="pause()">pause/stop</button>
<button onClick="resume()">resume</button>
```

Comment: Inline event handlers like `onclick` are [bad practice](/q/11737873/4642212). They’re an [obsolete, cumbersome, and unintuitive](/a/43459991/4642212) way to listen for events. Always [use `addEventListener`](//developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Building_blocks/Events#inline_event_handlers_%E2%80%94_dont_use_these) instead. Please _never_ suggest or encourage these attributes. The last browser that still needs them reached end of life nearly two decades ago.